# List of member reflection in C++

Tags: c++, rtti

In C++ there is no way to get information about the member variables of a class. This makes features like auto-serialization cumbersome to implement. It seems like this feature would be simple to add to the language. After all `typeid` and `std::typeinfo` makes it possible to get a unique identifier for a type. To illustrate how such a feature might work, see below:

```
// An integer constant corresponding to the number of members in the struct
type_members(A)::count

// An array of type_info corresponding to the members in the struct
type_members(A)::typeids

// An array of null terminated char* corresponding to the names of the members
type_members(A)::names

// Ann array of T A::* corresponding to the memory offsets of the members
// Where T is the type of the member at that index
type_members(A)::members
```

Has there been any discussion of adding a feature similar to this to the C++ standard? And if such a feature has been considered and rejected, why?

Comment: There's been a lot of interest in such a feature, but so far a proposal has not been accepted into the standard and delivered.

Comment: It's being [worked on](https://isocpp.org/std/status), it seems. Also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reflect

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4766.pdf but it is not based on typeids.